# How to get PHP to return JSON for inline form submission?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

tried searching this many times over but I must be missing something simple.

Simply put, I'm trying to submit my form over AJAX to a PHP script that returns JSON. I then perform actions client-side, based on the result of the submission (e.g. displaying errors). However, all I'm getting is my PHP script output - it's not being returned to my AJAX request.

Here is my form:

```
<form id="storyform" name="storyform" method="post" action="submitform.php" class="story-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <fieldset name="summary">
        <legend>Your Story <span class="required">(required)</span></legend>

        <p><label for="title">What is your story about?</label>
        <input type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="" name="title" /></p>

        <p><label for="description">What happened?</label>
        <textarea id="description" tabindex="" name="description" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea></p>
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

Here is the jQuery that handles the AJAX submission:

```
  jQuery("#storyform").submit(function(event) {

    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault(); 

    /* get some values from elements on the page: */
    var $form = $( this ),
        url = $form.attr( 'action' ),
        postData = {
            "title" = $form.find( '#title' ).val(),
            "description" = $form.find('#description').val()
        };

    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: postData,
        success: function(response){
            jQuery('#result').empty().append(response);
        }
    });
  });
```

I have a div with an ID of "result" after my form...

Then, submitform.php has;

```
if (!empty($_POST['title'])) {
    $new_post['post_title'] =  sanitize($_POST['title'], '');
} else {
    $errors['title'] = 'empty';
}

// Sanitise and prep the description
if (!empty($_POST['description'])){
    $new_post['post_content'] = sanitize($_POST['description']);
} else {
    $errors['description'] = 'empty';
}
echo json_encode($errors);
```

When submitting the form I expect to see my #results div populated with the JSON from submitform.php. Instead, I just get taken to submitform.php, away from my form, and all I see is that echoed JSON.

How do I get the JSON returned so that I can perform actions based on the content of it?

Comment: It sounds like your `submit` callback function isn't being executed at all, and the form submission is just being processed as normal; the most likely cause for that is a Javascript error that means the event handler isn't bound. Check Firebug, or some other development tool, for errors?

Comment: Thanks. No errors which is frustrating. An answer below suggested syntax but the data is being posted, is on the journey back from PHP that it's going to pot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this myself, but thanks for the help from others that did help get me there in the end.

It was merely a case, it seems, of wrapping my JS in document.ready, like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery("#storyform").submit(function(event) {

        /* stop form from submitting normally */
        event.preventDefault(); 

        /* get some values from elements on the page: */
        var $form = $( this ),
            url = $form.attr( 'action' ),
            postData = {
                title: $form.find( '#title' ).val(),
                description: $form.find('#description').val(),
                js: 'true'
            };

        /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: postData,
            success: function(response){
                jQuery('#result').empty().append(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My previous script wasn't triggering at all because it was running before the form had been rendered. I have made sure the response is coming back by having it print out in an alert.

Answer (score 4):

You have a Javascript error in the callback function for your `submit` event handler, which likely results in the event handler never being bound and the form submission proceeding as normal (giving you the results you weren't expecting).

This:

```
postData = {
    "title" = $form.find( '#title' ).val(),
    "description" = $form.find('#description').val()
};
```

is an incorrect object notation. The `key` and `value` should be separated using a colon (`:`), not an equals sign (`=`), and the key shouldn't have quotes, so change it to:

```
postData = {
    title : $form.find( '#title' ).val(),
    description : $form.find('#description').val()
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. I have made that change but still get the same results - to be clear, the data was making it to the PHP script and a var_dump() has shown that. Might it be that I should leave the form action blank and instead hard-code the submit URL into the AJAX call?

Comment: I've established that none of my Javascript is being triggered at all... welcome any suggestions on why that might be.

Answer (score 0):

Use this patter if you want to actually receive json in the correct content-type:

```
// Convert to JSON
$json = json_encode($data);

// Set content type
header('Content-type: application/json');

// Prevent caching
header('Expires: 0');

// Send Response
print($json);
exit;
```

Comment: Thank you, I've made that change and still get the same output although I'm sure the content type will help.

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript do this:

```
var postData = $form.serialize();
```

Also, you can do these checks on your client side before going server side (Unless you want something REALLY secure). Use the [validation engine plugin](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine).

Comment: According to the documentation the .$ajax data property can also accept an object, so serialization is not necessary.

Comment: Yes but what is sent to the server is an object, I am not sure if its processable by PHP itself.

Comment: What went to the server couldn't have been correct anyhow :-)

Comment: Thanks for your input. The PHP script is receiving the data okay. I started off with a var_dump() and die() to double check that, and I can see the JSON is formatted correctly from the submitted data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that your javascript is not being triggered.. Did you call `jQuery.noConflict()`?

Also make sure that your submit input (not shown in your form) does not have `name="submit"`, otherwise the jQuery `submit()` method won't work.